# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue (passing pointer into function)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have created a simple function to swap two pixels in `C++/SFML`, taking the two pixel indexes and the pointer to the pixel array.

I have been getting the error `"Expression must be a modifiable lvalue"`.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
void swapPixels(uint idx1, uint idx2, const sf::Color *pxColorBuffer){
    sf::Color temp = pxColorBuffer[idx1];
    pxColorBuffer[idx1] = pxColorBuffer[idx2];
    pxColorBuffer[idx2] = temp;
}
```

I am wondering why this doesn't work since I am passing in a pointer which should point to a modifiable value.

Comment: `const` means it's not modifiable.

Comment: As I already said, isn't the value to which the const pointer is pointing to modifiable? And if not, what would be an alternative?

Comment: This isn't a const pointer, its a pointer to const. So no, the value to which the pointer points to is not modifiable, its const. The alternative would be to remove the const.

Comment: Why try to reimplement [the wheel (aka `std::swap`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)? Won't solve your problem of trying to modify `const` data, but next time you need to swap something you'll know what to reach for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read about pointers, you should notice that

> `const TYPE *` as known as `TYPE const *` is a type of pointer, which points to a non modifiable `TYPE` object. Pointer itself could be changed, but the value it pointing to can't.
>
> `TYPE * const` is a type of pointer, which points to a modifiable `TYPE` object, but in this case pointer can't be changed.
>
> `const TYPE * const` as known as `TYPE const * const` is a type of pointer, which points to a non modifiable `TYPE` object and can't be changed.

Comment: just remove `const` qualifier in your function declaration before `sf::Color *`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the job, I think it's because of SFML which only allows me to get an unmodifiable instance of the pixels because image.getPixelsPrt() returns a const uint8_t*

Comment: Can you give some more information about your code please? Maybe the `pxColorBuffer` was `const` before you pass to the function? If so, you can't do the operation.

Comment: Alright so first I created two pointers:
      `uint8_t *pxByteBuffer;
      sf::Color *pxColorBuffer;`
Then I assigned the values and here image.getPixelsPtr() seems to return a const uint8_t*:
      `pxByteBuffer = image.getPixelsPtr();
      pxColorBuffer = reinterpret_cast<sf::Color*>(pxByteBuffer);`

Comment: Are you sure, that `reinterpret_cast<sf::Color*>(instance_of_uint8_t*)` is safe enough? Much possible it is cast problem. Is your program crushing or something else? If it is crushing can you provide crush message?

Comment: That's not really the point since `image.getPixelsPtr()` isn' t even putting out a modifiable pointer but a `const sf::Uint8*`

Comment: I mean, that you are trying to assign value of type `sf::Color` which initially was `uint8`. Are you sure, that it isn't cause of the problem? Are you sure, that casting from `uint8*` to `sf::Color*` is safe enough? for cases like this, avoid from usage of `reinterpret_cast`: use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` instead.

Comment: I think that it should be safe enough since sf::Color is nothing else than a uint32_t with some extra functions

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I think that the array is just read-only and you have to use `image.setPixel()` to modify it which is unfortunate because I would like to use one index instead of x, y coordinates